# Ruby Selenium - warning that :driver_path is deprecated

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir

Using Ruby selenium-webdriver 3.142.6

My tests work, but at the start of the run it displays the warning

```
WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] :driver_path is deprecated. Use :service with an instance of Selenium::WebDriver::Service instead.
```

According to Ruby docs Selenium::WebDriver::Service is a private API.

Searching the web for articles related to the warning has references to Capybara, RoR, and chromedriver-help, none of which I’m using. I've tried 'gem install webdrivers' but that fails.

Any recommendations on the path to take: ignore the deprecation message, or use the private Service class (and if so how to use it), or attempt to replace selenium-webdriver with webdrivers, or something else?

Here is the code that successfully creates the Selenium driver with the warning

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "test/unit"
require "byebug"

...

class GoogleTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def setup

    case $browser_arg
    when 'chrome'
        browser = :chrome
        driver_path = '/selenium_browser_drivers/chromedriver'
    when 'firefox'
        browser = :firefox
        driver_path = '/selenium_browser_drivers/geckodriver'
    else
          raise ArgumentError.new("Unexpected browser argument '#{$browser_arg}'") 
          exit      
    end
      @se = Selenium::WebDriver.for browser, :driver_path => driver_path

  end
...
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 3.142.0'
gem 'test-unit', '~> 3.3.0'
gem 'byebug', '~> 9.1.0'
```

Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    byebug (9.1.0)
    childprocess (3.0.0)
    power_assert (1.1.5)
    rubyzip (2.0.0)
    selenium-webdriver (3.142.6)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 4.0)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
    test-unit (3.3.4)
      power_assert

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  byebug (~> 9.1.0)
  selenium-webdriver (~> 3.142.0)
  test-unit (~> 3.3.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   2.0.2
```

Output from the command gem list

```
backports (3.15.0)
bigdecimal (default: 1.3.4)
builder (3.2.3)
bundler (2.0.2, 1.16.1, default: 1.16.0)
byebug (9.1.0)
childprocess (3.0.0, 0.8.0)
cmath (default: 1.0.0)
csv (default: 1.0.0)
cucumber (3.1.2)
cucumber-core (3.2.1)
cucumber-expressions (6.0.1)
cucumber-tag_expressions (1.1.1)
cucumber-wire (0.0.1)
date (default: 1.0.0)
dbm (default: 1.0.0)
did_you_mean (1.2.0)
diff-lcs (1.3)
etc (default: 1.0.0)
fcntl (default: 1.0.0)
ffi (1.9.18)
fiddle (default: 1.0.0)
fileutils (default: 1.0.2)
gherkin (5.1.0)
io-console (default: 0.4.6)
ipaddr (default: 1.2.0)
json (default: 2.1.0)
minitest (5.10.3)
multi_json (1.13.1)
multi_test (0.1.2)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
openssl (default: 2.1.0)
power_assert (1.1.5, 1.1.1)
psych (default: 3.0.2)
rake (12.3.0)
rdoc (default: 6.0.1)
rspec (3.9.0, 3.7.0, 3.6.0)
rspec-core (3.9.0, 3.7.1, 3.6.0)
rspec-expectations (3.9.0, 3.7.0, 3.6.0)
rspec-mocks (3.9.0, 3.7.0, 3.6.0)
rspec-support (3.9.0, 3.7.1, 3.7.0, 3.6.0)
rubyzip (2.0.0, 1.2.1)
scanf (default: 1.0.0)
sdbm (default: 1.0.0)
selenium-webdriver (3.142.6, 3.8.0)
stringio (default: 0.0.1)
strscan (default: 1.0.0)
test-unit (3.3.4, 3.2.7)
webrick (default: 1.4.2)
xmlrpc (0.3.0)
zlib (default: 1.0.0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid this error by explicitly assigning the driver_path variable even before you instantiate the driver variable. Look at the following code

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service.driver_path = "C:/Ruby26/chromedriver.exe"
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10
driver.navigate.to("https://www.google.com/")
driver.find_element(name: 'q').send_keys 'raja'
```

This code doesn't give that warning. Because I assign that value `Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service.driver_path = "C:/Ruby26/chromedriver.exe"` before I create the drive.

Comment: Thank you @Rajagopalan. That resolved the warning. On the other hand, according to https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium/WebDriver/Chrome/Service the Service class is private. Is it possible the class is no longer private and the docs are not updated? Or is using a private class "safer" than a deprecated feature?

Comment: driver_path is the class method which comes under Service which is open to access, Service class comes under `module Selenium
  module WebDriver
    module Chrome
      class Service < WebDriver::Service` Since there is a depreciation message, it's apparently they have changed something and I was not aware of what change it is.